# Auto rotate image based on exif orientation

Tags: javascript, image, orientation, exif

Problems with implementing the final piece off code that auto rotate the image based on exif data. Can somebody help me where to implement the right code.

```
function _(e) {
  return document.getElementById(e)
}

function handleFiles1(e) {

  var t = new Image;
  t.onload = function() {
    var e = document.createElement("canvas"),
      n = e.getContext("2d"),
      a = t.width,
      d = t.height,
      i = Math.min(maxW / a, maxH / d),
      o = a * i,
      r = d * i;
    e.width = o,
      e.height = r,
      n.drawImage(t, 0, 0, o, r);
    var l = new Image;
    l = e.toDataURL("image/jpeg"),
      document.getElementById("output1").src = l;
    var s = l.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""),
      u = new FormData;
    u.append("picture1", s),
      u.append("TC", TCodeVar);
    var p = new XMLHttpRequest;
    p.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler1, !1),
      p.addEventListener("load", completeHandler1, !1),
      p.addEventListener("error", errorHandler1, !1),
      p.open("POST", "UploadPage.php"),
      p.send(u)
  }, t.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: This does not look like code, that you have written. If you did ... give your variables some names and not just letters. To uglyfy your code there are tools. Probably no one will help you, because no one wants to dig through those variable names.

Comment: Yes, its not my code, thats true and the letters as var'names is not a plus also. But i'm stuck on how to implement a way off auto rotation on image. I hope some one will help me on the right track with this. Thank s for your reply

Comment: As I said - reformat your code, give it meaningful names and then someone might help you. Minimal effort please.